# WinForms button with image and text

Tags: .net, winforms, .net-3.5

I have a standard button on my `WinForm` with some text and an image. It looks like this:

[image: Button]

How can I set the button so that the image is aligned just to the left of the text? I have tried `ImageAlign`, but that doesn't seem to take into account the button's text.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Just found it.

You need to set:

`ImageAlign` to `MiddleRight`

`TextImageRelation` to `ImageBeforeText`

`TextAlign` as `MiddleCenter`

Answer (score 15):

For that you can use [TextImageRelation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s020taz2.aspx) Property to set it to `ImageBeforeText`:

> Specifies that the image is displayed horizontally before the text of a control.

[image]